# Determining causes of Bootstrap events being raised

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a Bootstrap accordion, and a button that expands all of the accordion panels.  This works fine.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="accordion-expand-all">Expand all</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#accordion-expand-all").click(function() {
    $(".panel-collapse").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("in") === false) {
            $(this).collapse("toggle");
        };
    });
});
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

I'd like to make it so that when a user clicks on a panel's header, if the accordion panel is collapsed, then the panel expands... **and** the window scrolls down such that the accordion panel's header is positioned at the top of the page.

A naive approach would be to invoke some function like `pageScrollToTop(expandedPanel)` to the Bootstrap `shown.bs.collapse` event.  But this conflicts with the "Expand All" button, which raises the `shown.bs.collapse` every time an accordion panel is expanded, and thus scrolling the page all over the place.

I know this is pretty unlikely, but when a `shown.bs.collapse` event is raised, is there a way of determining if it was raised by a user's *click*, versus being raised programmatically (as with the "Expand all" button)?  If so, my website would know when and when not to call `pageScrollToTop()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I attached a click handler to the accordion panel-headers, and created a "mock" `show.bs.collapse` event which scrolls the page afterwards (I peeked at the bootstrap.js code base to figure out how to do this).

The buttons just iterate over the accordion panels and invoke `$("#foo-panel").collapse("toggle")`, which raises the real `show.bs.collapse` event.

Answer (score 1):

You could trigger a once only event after someone clicks an unexpanded accordion item.  It's not quite what you were after (determining programmatically triggered vs user triggered event), but it should work.

```
$('a[data-toggle=collapse]').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).is('.collapsed')) {
        $(this.getAttribute('href')).one('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(document.body).stop().animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top});
        });
    }
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/97vju2b7/

Comment: This is a similar approach to the workaround that I ended up using: I attached a click handler to the accordion panel-headers, and created a "mock" `show.bs.collapse` event which scrolls the page afterwards (I peeked at Bootstrap's native code to figure out how to do this).  The buttons just iterate over the accordion panels and invoke `$("#foo-panel").collapse("toggle")`, which raises the real `show.bs.collapse` event.